# Checking for unaligned I/O on block devices

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have been playing around with block layer in Linux Kernel and have made a module to override make_request_fn of any block device. I want to note down the number and sizes of unaligned i/o requests (if any) on a block device whose make_request_fn I override. My question is regarding aligned and unaligned i/o, I understand that a lot of functions inside the block layer and even the compilers try to avoid unaligned i/o by using various methods.

A quote from the link ( https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.10/Documentation/unaligned-memory-access.txt#L1 ) shows a way to check for unaligned disk access is as follows :

"Unaligned memory accesses occur when you try to read N bytes of data starting
from an address that is not evenly divisible by N (i.e. addr % N != 0).
For example, reading 4 bytes of data from address 0x10004 is fine, but
reading 4 bytes of data from address 0x10005 would be an unaligned memory
access."

But this does not consider any logical, physical block sizes or even the alignment offset the underlying device may have. Are these considered while generating bio for i/o? Or are the sector numbers adjusted to accommodate this issue?

Sorry for the novice question, I am new at all this.

Comment: Block IO is block by nature. Means you will always access blocks in term of hardware block sizes and their addresses. Since that it should be aligned.

Comment: @0andriy, thanks for your reply but I am still a little confused. Any sector read/write is unaligned if it does not start at a physical block boundary or if its size is not equal to the physical block size. That means any struct bio issued must have its sector at a physical block boundary and size equal to the physical block size. Is this correct?

Comment: A driver is reading a whole sector using block access, even if you ask bytes [35, 623] out of 4k physical sector, caching it and VFS layer returns to user a slice of date from it.

Comment: @0andriy, Thanks for your quick reply. I dumped all sector numbers that each struct bio held and they were all multiples of 8 with an issue size of the entire physical block. This was helpful. Thanks.